# Left arrow key goes to beginning of line

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

For no known reason the left arrow key has started behaving as if I'm pressing Command + left arrow. There is no way I can get the cursor to move one letter at a time except if I hold the shift key down but that selects the text which I don't want. Everything else on the keyboard works as expected inc. right arrow key and the option + left arrow moves one word at a time.

Montery MBA 2015

Grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Does the [on screen Accessibility Keyboard](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-accessibility-keyboard-mchlc74c1c9f/mac) help you determine if this is software or hardware?

Comment: Thanks @bmike. Super useful tip! The on screen Accessibility Keyboard left arrow key behaves the same way, so it must be software related. I run Karabner but that's not the culprit because if I quit it, the left arrow key still misbehaves.